# Как унаследовать переменную self.xxx(xxx - рандомное название) из другого класса

Tags: python

У меня есть 3 файла, один запускает все, другой нужен для ввода значений от пользователя, а 3 уже делает логику, но произошла проблема. Я хочу взять из файла Input.py перменную self.start_exp, но почему то пишет эту ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MYFOLDERS/Programming/Projects/Levels_ranks/Logic.py", line 36, in <module>
    Logic()
  File "C:/MYFOLDERS/Programming/Projects/Levels_ranks/Logic.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.current_exp = self.start_exp
AttributeError: 'Logic' object has no attribute 'start_exp'
```

Хотя даже pycharm дает поставить эту переменную.

Вот файл запуска(Main.py)

```
import Input
import Logic
import Writer


Input.Input()
Logic.Logic()
```

Файл загрузки того что ввел пользователь(Input.py)

```
import os


class Input:
    def __init__(self):
        self.advanced = False
        self.max_lvl = 0
        self.last_lvl_exp = 0
        self.start_exp = 0
        self.percent = 0
        self.max_give_exp = 0
        self.max_percent_lvl = 0
        self.user_max_percent = 0
        self.input_on_advanced()
        self.input_max_lvl()
        self.input_last_lvl_exp()
        self.check_advanced()


    def input_on_advanced(self):
        while True:
            self.advanced = input("Введите, хотите ли Вы использовать расширенный режим?\n")

            if self.advanced.lower() in ("да", "yes", "lf", "+"):
                self.advanced = True
                os.system("cls")
                break
            elif self.advanced.lower() in ("нет", "no", "ytn", "-"):
                self.advanced = False
                os.system("cls")
                break
            else:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста да/нет!\n")

    def input_max_lvl(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.max_lvl = int(input("Введите, какой Вы хотите максимальный лвл?\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")

    def input_last_lvl_exp(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.last_lvl_exp = int(input("Введите, сколько очков Вы хотите на последнем уровне?\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")

    def check_advanced(self):
        if self.advanced == True:
            self.input_start_exp()
            self.input_percent()
            self.input_max_give_exp()
            self.input_user_max_percent()

    def input_start_exp(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.start_exp = int(input("Введите, сколько очков Вы хотите на первом уровне?\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")

    def input_percent(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.percent = int(input("Введите, насколько процентов Вы хотите увеличивать каждый лвл?\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")

    def input_max_give_exp(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.max_give_exp = int(input("Введите, насколько Вы хотите максимально повышать каждый уровень?\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")

    def input_user_max_percent(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.user_max_percent = int(input("Введите, на каком проценте включать уменьшение опыта\n"))
                os.system("cls")
                break
            except ValueError:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Введите, пожалуйста число!\n")
```

А это файл со скриптом(Logic.py)

```
from Input import *


class Logic(Input):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_lvl = True
        self.on_percent = True
        self.give_exp = 0
        self.percent_max_lvl = 0
        self.minus_exp = 0
        self.current_exp = self.start_exp
        self.percent_left = 0

    def procent_lvl(self):
        # Высчитывает на сколько прибавлять каждый лвл
        if self.first_lvl is False and self.on_percent is True and self.give_exp < self.max_give_exp:
            self.give_exp = self.current_exp / 100 * self.percent

    def calculations(self):
        # Вычесляется текущий процент опыта от последнего лвла
        self.percent_max_lvl = self.last_lvl_exp / self.current_exp
        self.percent_max_lvl = 100 / self.percent_max_lvl

        if self.percent_max_lvl > self.user_max_percent and self.current_exp is self.max_give_exp and self.on_percent is True:
            # Считает сколько осталось процентов до конца
            self.percent_left = 100 - self.percent_max_lvl

            # Считает сколько надо опыта до конца
            self.fix_minus_exp = self.last_lvl_exp / 100
            self.minus_exp = self.fix_minus_exp * self.percent_left

            # Добавить: cчитает какой ранг
            #           iTopMinus = Maxlvl - i + 1
```

Для тех кто не понял, в файле Logic.py есть строка: "self.current_exp = self.start_exp" в самом верху, и именно на ней ошибка

Comment: для тех, кто не понял - в классе Logic нет свойства start_exp и именно об этом ошибка и сообщает. О чем вопрос - непонятно. Советую прочитать еще разок в учебнике про классы, чтобы понимать что такое self и почему self.start_exp в одном месте не имеет ни малейшего отношения к self.start_exp в другом.

Comment: Хорошо, но как тогда перенести эту переменную в другой файл?

Comment: Переменную в другой файл никак не перенести. Можно взять значение свойства объекта класса.  Но для этого нужно этот объект создать. Почитайте все таки учебник.

Comment: Я в принципе решил проблему, жалко что придется все переписывать

Comment: Оказывается и переписывать нечего не надо. Написал в ответе как это можно сделать

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы делаете наследование, то класс-потомок наследует методы родителя, но при этом конструктор класса-предка, то есть его метод `__init__`, не выполняется автоматически, его нужно вызвать самому в конструкторе класса-потомка (ну или где вам это нужно):

```
class Logic(Input):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # <-- вызов конструктора класса-предка
        self.first_lvl = True
        self.on_percent = True
        ...
```

После вызова конструктора класса-предка в вашем классе-потомке появятся те поля, которые создаст конструктор класса-предка.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы это работало я изменил в файле Main.py 2 строчки с

```
import Input
import Logic
import Writer


Input.Input()
Logic.Logic()
```

на

```
import Input
import Logic
import Writer

input_file = Input.Input()
logic_file = Logic.Logic(input_file)
```

И изменил файл Logic.py с

```
from Input import *


class Logic(Input):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_lvl = True
        self.on_percent = True
        self.give_exp = 0
        self.percent_max_lvl = 0
        self.minus_exp = 0
        self.current_exp = self.start_exp
        self.percent_left = 0

    def procent_lvl(self):
        # Высчитывает на сколько прибавлять каждый лвл
        if self.first_lvl is False and self.on_percent is True and self.give_exp < self.max_give_exp:
            self.give_exp = self.current_exp / 100 * self.percent

    def calculations(self):
        # Вычесляется текущий процент опыта от последнего лвла
        self.percent_max_lvl = self.last_lvl_exp / self.current_exp
        self.percent_max_lvl = 100 / self.percent_max_lvl

        if self.percent_max_lvl > self.user_max_percent and self.current_exp is self.max_give_exp and self.on_percent is True:
            # Считает сколько осталось процентов до конца
            self.percent_left = 100 - self.percent_max_lvl

            # Считает сколько надо опыта до конца
            self.fix_minus_exp = self.last_lvl_exp / 100
            self.minus_exp = self.fix_minus_exp * self.percent_left

            # Добавить: cчитает какой ранг
            #           iTopMinus = Maxlvl - i + 1
```

на

```
class Logic:
    def __init__(self, Input):
        self.input = Input
        self.first_lvl = True
        self.on_percent = True
        self.give_exp = 0
        self.percent_max_lvl = 0
        self.minus_exp = 0
        self.current_exp = self.input.start_exp
        print(self.current_exp)
        self.percent_left = 0

    def procent_lvl(self):
        # Высчитывает на сколько прибавлять каждый лвл
        if self.first_lvl is False and self.on_percent is True and self.give_exp < self.max_give_exp:
            self.give_exp = self.current_exp / 100 * self.percent

    def calculations(self):
        # Вычесляется текущий процент опыта от последнего лвла
        self.percent_max_lvl = self.last_lvl_exp / self.current_exp
        self.percent_max_lvl = 100 / self.percent_max_lvl

        if self.percent_max_lvl > self.user_max_percent and self.current_exp is self.max_give_exp and self.on_percent is True:
            # Считает сколько осталось процентов до конца
            self.percent_left = 100 - self.percent_max_lvl

            # Считает сколько надо опыта до конца
            self.fix_minus_exp = self.last_lvl_exp / 100
            self.minus_exp = self.fix_minus_exp * self.percent_left

            # Добавить: cчитает какой ранг
            #           iTopMinus = Maxlvl - i + 1
```

Но здесь не настроены остальные переменные, настроена только self.current_exp = self.input.start_exp

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите